# Docker multi stage optimization causes an error with node.js

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

Hello I'm working with my first docker project but having a problem reducing the image size.

```
FROM node:14.15.0-alpine

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
# COPY ./medichis-kubernetes/config.json .

RUN npm install && npm run build

EXPOSE 7575

CMD [ "node", "./dist/src/bin/www.js" ]
```

The single stage docker image with this code is run okay but,
the multi stage docker image with the following codes causes an error.

```
# Stage 1: Build Stage
FROM node:14.15.0-alpine AS BUILD_IMAGE
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Production Stage
FROM node:14.15.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=BUILD_IMAGE /app/config.json ./

EXPOSE 7575

CMD [ "node", "./dist/src/bin/www.js" ]
```

`(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './src/modules' (Use` node --trace-warnings ...`to show where the warning was created) (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag`--unhandled-rejections=strict`(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2) (node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './.banner' (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag`--unhandled-rejections=strict `(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)`

1. I checked the image is created right with a tag.
2. I built npm project locally, and the directory is Root/dist/src/bin/www.js that is same as the one inside the dockerfile.

What do you think I can do more?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the `./src/modules` and `.banner` file names in your code somewhere?

Comment: I wrote codes from others' projects but I should have copied those paths for mine. It seems like my project structure(path reading) is kinda irrational that dist directory already has src directory but I shoud copy src independantly. Thank you for you comment!